# Angular js : How to call a controller in .run method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am developing a web application in angular js.
I want to do some sequential execution of function.

> quoteController.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

 angular
    .module("autoQuote")
        //Do initalization on page load
       .run(["$log","$rootScope","$state","dtoResource","questionResource",function($log,$rootScope,$state,dtoResource,"questionResource") { 
          $rootScope.AutoQuote = dtoResource.rc1Step1DTO();
          $rootScope.questions = questionResource.getQuestions($rootScope.AutoQuote.postAutoQuoteObj.SessionInfo.StateCode);
          console.log($rootScope);
          $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            if (fromState.name === "") { 

            }
          });
        }])
}());
```

questionsCtrl.js

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular
.module("autoQuote")
.factory("questionResource",["$resource","$http","$state",questionResource]);

function questionResource($resource,$http,$state)
{   
    return{
     getQuestions : function(stateCode) {
         var userState = stateCode != "" ? stateCode : 'CA';
         $http.get('assets/themes/easyquote/js/questions/'+userState+'.json')
         .then(function(response) {
            return response.data;  
        }); 
    }
   }
}
```

}());

In .run I want to execute
`$rootScope.AutoQuote = dtoResource.rc1Step1DTO();`   and `$rootScope.questions = $rootScope.questionsCtrl();`

1. when `rc1Step1DTO` execution gets complete and successfull then only questionsCtrl execution should start.
2. I am unable to execute questionsCtrl function from `.run`. is says function is undefined.

Please let  me know how can we handle such situation in angular js.

Comment: im worry that you're not able to call controller scope variable from 'run'. But I believe using service or factory could handle this problem like 'dtoResource' in the code

Comment: You can not call the controller inside .run but you can use services to access the function in that way you can access the controllers function

Comment: You *can* call the controller inside run with `$controller('questionsCtrl')`. The question is *why* do you want to do this? Why don't you create simply `<div ng-controller="questionsCtrl"></div>` and initialize everything there?

Comment: Ok,  I should create questionsCtrl controller into factory. but how I will make these calls synchronous. I want rc1Step1DTO when completes execution then only questionsCtrl should execute.

Comment: @Greatym.com How is this controller initialized? Via router or via `ng-controller`..?